# How to insert multiple rows from one column?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, insert

I want to insert multiple rows from one column by splitting column value. But I have to do that without cursors because of performance issues.

Every `value` is splitted to 6 chars length values. Then these values also splitted to 3, 1 and 2 chars length values to insert different columns in table B.

I think giving a sample will clarify my question:

#### Table A

```
ID      Value
1       ABCDEFGHJKLM
2       NOPRST
3       NULL VALUE
```

I want to insert these values into table B like this format

#### Table B

```
ID     Value1       Value2       Value3
1       ABC          D            EF
1       GHJ          K            LM
2       NOP          R            ST
```

Comment: What is the criteria of splitting the Value string of Tabale A? @mehmet

Comment: It is splitted to 6 chars length values. Then these values also splitted to 3, 1 and 2 chars length values to insert different columns in table B. @techdo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supposing 600(100 rows) as maximum length of value:

```
insert into tableB
select id, substr(value,n*6+1,3), substr(value,n*6+4,1), substr(value,n*6+5,2)
from tableA 
     join (select level-1 as n from dual connect by level <= 100)
       on length(value) > n*6;
```

see [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d8510/2).

Comment: Hi, I think it makes almost what I want but in my example for row 2 in Table A. This code adds also one empty row for next 6 chars. Where can I check If null control in this code?

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I add where clause length(trim(substr(value,n*6+1,3))) > 0 at the end of the query. And Now I get the exact result.

Comment: I think something is wrong with your data. I've tested on sqlfiddle. See the edit.

Comment: Yes, I see your edit. My Table A is also a select query, maybe it causes null values.  Thanks Again.

Answer (score 3):

```
select ID,
    SUBSTR(value,number*6+1,3),
    SUBSTR(value,number*6+4,1),
    SUBSTR(value,number*6+5,2)
from yourtable,
    (select 0  as number union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 
            union  select 5 union select 6) as numbers 
      /* etc up to the max length of your string /6 */
where LEN(value)>number*6
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Please convert it to ORACLE SQL.. 
Even though, its using a while loop, its doing bulk inserts..and the loop is executed as per the length of maximun length of value in the table

```
declare @max_len int=0;
declare @counter int=0;
declare @col_index int=1;
select @max_len=MAX(len(Value)) from TableA

while (@max_len/6 > @counter)
begin
    set @counter=@counter+1

    Insert into TableB

    select ID,substring(Value,@col_index,3),
              substring(Value,@col_index+3,1),
              substring(Value,@col_index+4,2) 
    from TableA where substring(Value,@col_index,3) is not null

    set @col_index=@col_index+6
end
```